# ofstream - permission denied, id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a very basic piece of code to open in C++ and file handle and add some data to it.

I have now tried two different functions to do this but both return the same messages in my compiler/IDE.

The code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    FILE *kf;
    kf = fopen("c:\\file.txt", "a");
    fputs ("fopen example", kf);
    fclose (kf);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows

```
Permission denied
Id returned 1 exit status
```

I have also tried using another function

```
ofstream file;
file.open("c:\\file.txt");
file << "testing";
file.close();
```

but it returns the exact same error.
I have also created a file called file.txt in c:\, but it doesn't change anything.

compiler/editor = **Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2**

OS = **Windows XP** I am using only account available, which should be admin

Comment: Consider using a path that you're confident you have write access to.  Windows has made strides in privilege separation in its last few releases.  If you're not a privileged user, you might very well not have permission to write there (root of `C:`).

Comment: @BrianCain I just tried making some directories within c, it still gives the same error. Also updated my post with more info

Comment: copy the whole project directory to "My Document" then reopen the project and try to compile. it appear you have the write privilage to the directory but Dev C++ compiler doesn't.

Comment: My take: `Id` should be `ld`, the linker, because your executable cannot be overwritten (maybe it's still running), so linking fails.

Comment: @chris thats correct, this is the reason

Answer (score 2):

Before writing any code, attempt to create a file using NotePad, WordPad, or some other app in the `C:\` directory.  If you cannot create a file using NotePad, then you can't create one with your own program.

Therefore either write to a drive\directory you have permission to, or change your access rights to the root directory (which I wouldn't recommend, but just to give you another option).

Comment: I did state in my opening post that I did create a file in the directory, it didnt change anything.

Comment: Right-click & select run as administrator on the IDE shortcut. THEN open whatever project or file you want to compile/run. Had the same problem with `Visual Studio` and that solved it.